# Save if new many to many relationships Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, many-to-many

I have two models : Event and Soundcloud.

Both are defined to be a many-to-many relationship in Laravel and it is working fine.

I am saving the soundcloud and population the pivot table event_soundcloud by doing this

```
foreach ($data as $artist => $url) {
     $soundcloud = Soundcloud::firstOrNew(['artist_name' => $artist, 'link' => $url]);
    $event->soundclouds()->save($soundcloud);
}
```

That function is called every 10 minutes and each time the same records are added to the pivot table.

Is there a way to do the same thing but adding records in pivot table only if it does not exist already ?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I did to make it work. I guess you cannot do it in one step

```
 $soundcloud = Soundcloud::firstOrNew(['artist_name' => $artist, 'link' => $url]);
 $soundcloud->save();
 $event->soundclouds()->sync([$soundcloud->id], false);
```